# Trying to plot two samples in R

Tags: density-plot

I'm a newbie and a late bloomer in R programming and this is also my first time to ask here after a year of searching and learning in the background.

I am trying to learn R programming and statistics at the same time. I have come across this principle that when we add a constant to a sample and re-calculate its mean, we would see that the mean would move right or left depending on the constant we added. So I wanted to knit this knowledge with R and show this in a plot.

I created my own data.frame below:

```
x1 <- c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5)
x1.name <- "sample.1"
df <- data.frame(x1)
names(df) <- c(x1.name)
df <- df %>% 
      mutate(sample.2 = sample.1 + 6)
plot(density(df$sample.1)) 
lines(density(df$sample.2))
axis(1, at=seq(0, 13, by=1))
```

My problem is the width of the plot ends in #7 and I don't get to see the full bell curve of the second sample. Is there a way to fix this? I know there are other ways to plot this and I'd appreciate your suggestions. I'd just like to see this code through.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use `ylim`as

```
plot(density(sample.1),xlim=c(-1,15))
```

and if you are not bounded to use **Forward Pipe Operator**, then you can use following code. (I have no idea how this operator works)

```
sample.1 <- c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5)
sample.2 = sample.1+ 6

plot(density(sample.1),xlim=c(-1,15)) 
lines(density(sample.2))
axis(1, at=seq(0, 15, by=1))
```

Comment: Thank you Angel! 

I used your code to edit mine and now it works. I just edited this part:

plot(density(df$sample.1), xlim=c(-1,15))
and this
axis(1, at=seq(0, 15, by=1))

Both work!

Comment: @Ramon Jalmaani can you please mark it as your answer...?